# input lose focus when other element is focused

Tags: html, css, focus

I'm trying to create a custom component using only CSS and HTML.
The behavior of the component will be like: when the input is selected (has focus) another container is open. 
The problem is when the container is opened the input lose focus and the container is closed on first click :(

So How can I have that input focus focused when I'm on the opened container focused ?

```
<div class="block">
    <label>Field</label>
    <input type="text" tabindex="-1"/>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="infront">
         Keep this bastard open.<br/>
        <br/>
        while clicking on this div
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px;
}

.infront{display: none;}

.block input[type="text"]:focus ~ .infront {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    width: 80%;
    right: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

**[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/DMfvx/533/)**

Comment: sorry i cant follow you, i dont really understand what the problem is

Comment: I think your code works fine

Comment: @MKAD when the input is focused, the ".infront" container is opened, if I click into ".infront" container that is hiding because the input lose its focus. What I need is to have that container opened if I click inside and hide if I click outside that container ....

Comment: @Sharmila not really because yes, the ".infront" is opened but if you click inside that container will be hiding and I need to be hidden only when I click outside that container .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care of the state of .infront container states as well.

Update your CSS to this

```
.block input[type="text"]:focus ~ .infront
, .infront:hover
, .infront:active 
, .infront:focus {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    width: 80%;
    right: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not do it only with HTML and CSS. You will need some jquery code like this:

```
$(.block input[type=text]).on('focus', function(e) {
    $('.infront').show();
});
```

Comment: not really, the container ".infront" is show from my CSS so no need jQuery show. What I need is to keep that ".infront" container open if I click inside that and hide container if I click outside that container ...

Comment: @burebistaruler You are right, but if you want to keep this as display:block, you have to change it with js and then if you focus out, it wont be removed